# Attributes - Where Are Advanced Settings Stored

Tags: attributes

I can't seem to find where additional attribute information like the value for `is_searchable` or `apply_to` stored in the database? I can't find this data anywhere in the `eav_*` tables.

Answer (score 2):

That information is in the `catalog_eav_attribute` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','default_setup')
     ->getEntityType('catalog_product', 'additional_attribute_table');
```

This will tell you where extra attribute properties are stored for a given entity type, (`catalog_product` in my example.) This is usually going to be `[entity type]_eav_attribute`